# How to install certain ruby gems on windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rubygems

I am creating a social network for a product, and am trying to install a platform for social networking in rails on my computer. But when I try to install the gem, I get this error message:

```
  C:\Ruby22-x64>gem install social_stream-oauth2_server
  Fetching: attr_required-1.0.0.gem (100%)
  Successfully installed attr_required-1.0.0
  Fetching: httpclient-2.7.1.gem (100%)
  Successfully installed httpclient-2.7.1
  Fetching: rack-oauth2-1.0.10.gem (100%)
  Successfully installed rack-oauth2-1.0.10
  Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  ERROR:  Error installing social_stream-oauth2_server:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

  C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160124-10888-1dyh2d0.rb   extconf.rb
  *** extconf.rb failed ***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
  libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
  need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    extconf.rb:110:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:110:in `configure_compile_options'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
    from extconf.rb:517:in `new'
    from extconf.rb:517:in `<main>'

    extconf failed, exit code 1

    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-   x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-    mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
```

How do I install this gem to where any other software doesn't interfere with the installation?

Comment: Try installing using Bundler.

Comment: Also try using older version of ruby like 1.9.3 or use 32bit ruby version.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of ruby. Also, it keeps stating that DevKit is not allowing the gem to be installed.